# OpenGL - Rotating a 2D Asteroids Ship

Tags: c, opengl, rotation

So I've been googling this out the wazoo and going through all sorts of resources - texts, lectures, etc. - but I'm either missing something or just not grasping it correctly. For a class in OpenGL we need to design an Asteroids game, which seems like a simple enough concept, but I'm finding it very difficult to get the movement of my ship down right. I know that we need to translate our ship to the origin, perform the rotation, and translate it back to its appropriate position - the problem I'm facing is understanding the execution of it. The code I have for drawing a ship is this so far:

```
void
drawShip(Ship *s)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    myTranslate2D(s->x, s->y);
    float x = s->x, y = s->y;
    myRotate2D(s->phi);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(s->x + s->dx, s->y + s->dy + 3);
    glVertex2f(s->x + s->dx-2, s->y + s->dy - 3);
    glVertex2f(s->x + s->dx, s->y + s->dy -1.5);
    glVertex2f(s->x + s->dx + 2, s->y + s->dy - 3);
    glEnd();
    myTranslate2D(s->x - x, s->y - y);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

With rotation and motion determined by the following variables, which are correctly modified in a Keyboard function:

```
if (left == 1)
    {
        ship.phi -= 0.3;
    }
    if (right == 1)
    {
        ship.phi += 0.3;
    }
    if (up == 1)
    {
        ship.dx += -2.0*sin(ship.phi);
        ship.dy += 2.0*cos(ship.phi);
    }
    if (down == 1)
    {
        ship.dx += 2.0*sin(ship.phi);
        ship.dy += -2.0*cos(ship.phi);
    }
    drawShip(&ship);
```

Once I get the rotation down, I'm confident that I can get the rest of everything done. As it is, the above code will allow my object to either rotate on the origin or around it, but it will not rotate in place unless it is directly on the origin. The ship itself has been initialized to points of (0,0), (25, 25), and (50, 50), and for my purposes the origin of the screen (0,0) is the bottom left corner.

Can someone help me understand why my ship will not rotate in place, and only about the origin? I expect that it has something to do with how I'm performing my translations and rotation, but I'm at a loss as to what.

Comment: Looks like C. Do not add C++ tag for C questions, they are different languages!

Answer (score 1):

Your draw function seems wrong.
Your ship design shouldn't depend on it's position. What this means is that the coordinates of the vertices should always be the same. Then use GlTranslate and Rotate to get it into the right position. You also do a translate after you draw and before you pop the matrix. That doesn't do anything because matrix changes only apply to vertices defined after the matrix change.

The structure should be something like this:

```
// Make sure the origin is in the 0, 0  of your space.
GlPushMatrix();  // Save this setup
GlTranslate(ship.x, ship.y);  // Location of the ship.
GlRotate(ship.phi);  // Or whatever is the name of the angle of the ship.

DrawShip();  // Draws the sprite/wireframe/object you want.
GlPopMatrix();  // Return to the original setup.
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually pointed me down the right path! What you were showing was effectively what I was doing, but with the caveat that I was doing strange modifications within the line-loop itself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I actually figured it out with some poking. The problem was that I've been drawing the changes in velocity directly from the draw, instead of calculating the new position based on velocity and translating as such. Here's the fixed code:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    float newX = s->x + s->dx, newY = s->y + s->dy;
    myTranslate2D(newX, newY);
    myRotate2D(s->phi);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(s->x, s->y + 3); 
    glVertex2f(s->x - 2, s->y - 3);
    glVertex2f(s->x, s->y - 1.5);
    glVertex2f(s->x + 2, s->y - 3);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
```